# Alterando cores da página com name

Tags: javascript

Fiz uma rotina que altera todas as cores da página, porém só funciona se for pela `id`, por exemplo:

```
document.getElementById("PriColor").style["background-color"] = "rgb(155,155,155)";
```

Tem uma forma de eu fazer com o `name` dos campos? Por exemplo:

```
document.getElementsByName("SecColor").style["background-color"] = "rgb(111,160,253)";
```

Quando uso pelo `name`, ele retorna o erro:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'background-color' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque a função `getElementsByName` retorna uma lista de elementos do DOM, enquanto a função `getElementById` retorna apenas um elemento do DOM. Isso também é perceptível pela semântica do método (plural e singular).

O código correto deveria ser:

```
document.getElementsByName("SecColor").forEach(element => {
    element.style["background-color"] = "rgb(111,160,253)";
})
```

Comment: Entendi @Marcel, obrigado pela informação !!

Answer (score 0):

Como um `id` deve ser único na página, logo a função `getElementById` é no singular, porque você só vai selecionar um único elemento.

Já a função `getElementsByName`, que é no plural (no singular não existe), sugere que você irá selecionar uma lista de nós (*nodelist*) que é a coleção do valor especificado na função (assim como `getElementsByTagName` e `getElementsByClassName`).

Ao contrário do `id`, os `name`, `class` e `tag` podem ter 1 ou mais ocorrências na página, e sendo assim, a função `getElementsByName` irá criar um objeto *nodelist* com todos os elementos que tiverem o `name` especificado, criando uma array com os elementos. Para acessar esses elementos você precisa especificar um índice, começando do `0`:

```
document.getElementsByName("SecColor")    // todos os elementos (nodelist)
document.getElementsByName("SecColor")[0] // 1º elemento
document.getElementsByName("SecColor")[1] // 2º elemento
document.getElementsByName("SecColor")[2] // 3º elemento
etc..
```

Para alterar todos os elementos do *nodelist*, você deve fazer um *loop* percorrendo cada um dos elementos, como sugeriu a resposta do Marcel. Porém, vou deixar uma sugestão mais compatível usando o `for` tradicional (o `forEach` não funciona nos navegadores Microsoft):

```
for(var x = 0; x < document.getElementsByName("SecColor").length; x++){
   els[x].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(111,160,253)";
}
```